# Using "will_paginage" gem the correct way - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I'm trying to implement the `will_paginage` gem for my application right now. I'm getting an error when trying to add it to my controller here is what it's saying: `undefined method "paginate" for #<Assignment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f82f83548f0>`
Has anybody seen this error before?

Here is my full code with error:

### Controller:

```
  def dashboard
    @assignments = current_account.assignments.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    @invitation = Invitation.new

    render locals: { admin_policy: admin_policy }
  end
```

So I'm trying to paginate a collection obviously... So why this error:

### Error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that 'will_paginate' included to Gemfile, `bundle install` was started and the server was restarted?

Comment: It was the server

Comment: Check for the will_paginate gem in the Gemfile.lock

Comment: Controller code looks fine, make sure gem is included, restart server

Comment: Please check if `will_paginate` is correctly installed. Open `rails console` and try `defined? WillPaginate` and `ActiveRecord::Base.respond_to? :paginate`. If any is `nil/false` then it is not.